# NextJS 13 Data Fetching

Tags: next.js, axios, fetch

Is there anyway of custom baseURL for their [fetch](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching/fetching) method?

For example in [axios](https://axios-http.com/docs/instance):

```
const instance = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'https://some-domain.com/api/',
  timeout: 1000,
  headers: {'X-Custom-Header': 'foobar'}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding you want to consume a native method to fetch data(API).
For that JS has a **fetch('url)** method. If you just want to fetch data from an end point, then just pass the url and you will get the result **(Use await with it)**

```
let data=fetch('https://some-domain.com/api/');
```

Its easy way, or you can define the whole body with header.

```
fetch("https://some-domain.com/api/", {
  method: "POST",
  body: JSON.stringify({
    your: data,
  }),
  headers: {
    "Content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8"
  }
});
```

Above snippet is for POST method. Other methods are similar to this.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no such thing as baseUrl for `fetch Api`.

You can instead create a wrapper from a `fetchApi`, so that you only need to pass the URL once.

```
const fetchWrapper = (path: string) => {
   return fetch(`${BASE_URL}${path}`)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm gonna go out out on a limb here, but you you could also use `.env`-files.

I use this approach in a project currently,

```
NEXT_PUBLIC_BASE_URI=http://localhost:3000
NEXT_PUBLIC_ROOT_ID=8793d6a9-a604-448d-92o0-266cca56f89f
NEXT_PUBLIC_CMS_URI=http://localhost:45959
NEXT_PUBLIC_CONTENT_URI=http://localhost:45959/umbraco/delivery/api/v1/content
NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URI=http://api.my-development-server.com
NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URI_v3=https://www.production-server-name.io/api/v3/
```

Then you replace a url in your components with `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URI}`

This way, you have a global "baseUrl". And this url is different between environments used during development. They're all set and read in the .env-files. (.env.local, .env.development, .env.production ans so on).

Don't forget to exclude appropiate .env-files when pushing to repo. You don't want the wrong files floating around in production.

*Source: Personal experience*